# Probability density function with the help of the Laplace (Fourier) transform

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, laplace-transform

I am reading a paper that derives a closed form expression of the following probability using properties from Fourier transform,

$$ \mathbb{P} \biggl( F \geq T \ (I+W) \biggl)$$

**Assumptions:**

1- Assume that the $F$ has a finite first moment and admits a square integrable density $f(y)$.

2- $I$ and $W$ are independent and either one admits a density which is square integrable.

3- $I+W$ admits a density $g(t)$.

4- $T$ is a constant

The proof is presented next,

**Proof**
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \biggl( F \geq T(I+W) \biggl)&= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(y) \  \mathbb{P} \biggl(I+W<y/T \biggl)\\
&= \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(y) \ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(t) \ 1(0<t<y/T) dt \\
&\stackrel{?}{=} \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(y)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathcal{L}_{I}(-2 i \pi s)\mathcal{L}_{W}(-2i\pi s)\times \frac{e^{2i\pi ys/T }-1}{2i\pi s} ds dy\\
&\stackrel{?}{=} \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(y)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathcal{L}_{I}(-2 i \pi s T)\mathcal{L}_{W}(-2i\pi sT)\times \frac{e^{2i\pi ys }-1}{2i\pi s} ds dy\\
&\stackrel{?}{=}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathcal{L}_{I}(2 i \pi s T)\mathcal{L}_{W}(2i\pi sT)\times \frac{\mathcal{L_F}(-2i\pi s )-1}{2i\pi s} ds 
\end{align}$$

where the notation $\mathcal{L}_{I}(.),\mathcal{L}_{W}(.), \mathcal{L}_{F}(.)$ represent the Laplace transform of $I,W$ and $F$.

**Questions**

My questions are regarding the last three steps marked with (?).

I understand that there is a convolution step for the probability density function $I+W$ which becomes in the frequency domain multiplication between two transforms, however I don't understand how the authors arrive to the argument of the Laplace that is $-2 i \pi s$.

The authors claim that this can be done using Plancherel-Parseval theroem. I have added the theorem below

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)\ g(t) \ dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(s)\ \overline{\hat{g}(s)} \ ds $$

where for all functions $f,g$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the Fourier of Transform at $s\in \mathbb{R}$ when it exists is given by  $$\hat{f}(s)= \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2i\pi t s} f(t) \ dt $$
$$\hat{g}(s)= \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2i\pi t s} g(t) \ dt $$
and $ \ \overline{\hat{g}(s)}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $\hat{g}(s)$.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems to me that the densities of $I,W$ are only supported
on $\left[0,\infty\right)$, otherwise I don't see how the derivation
can be true. Hence, I will assume this in the following.

Then, let us denote the densities of $I,W$ by $g_{I},g_{W}$, respectively.
This implies
$$
\overline{\widehat{g_{I}}\left(\xi\right)}=\overline{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_{I}\left(x\right)\cdot e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,{\rm d}x}=\int_{0}^{\infty}g_{I}\left(x\right)\cdot e^{2\pi ix\xi}\,{\rm d}x=\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(-2\pi i\xi\right).
$$
An analogous formula holds for $\mathcal{L}_{W}$.

Now note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\mathcal{F}1_{0<t<y/T}\right)\left(\xi\right) & = & \int_{0}^{y/T}e^{-2\pi it\xi}\,{\rm d}t\\
 & = & \frac{e^{-2\pi it\xi}}{-2\pi i\xi}\bigg|_{t=0}^{y/T}\\
 & = & \frac{e^{-2\pi iy\xi/T}-1}{-2\pi i\xi}
\end{eqnarray*}
Finally, $g=g_{I}\ast g_{W}$ (because $I,W$ are independent), so
that $\mathcal{F}g=\widehat{g_{I}}\cdot\widehat{g_{W}}$ (by the convolution theorem).

As $g_{I},g_{W}$
are square integrable, so are the Fourier transforms $\widehat{g_{I}},\widehat{g_{W}}$
(by Plancherel's theorem). But densities are always integrable, so
that $\widehat{g_{I}},\widehat{g_{W}}\in C_{0}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.
Hence $\widehat{g_{I}}\cdot\widehat{g_{W}}\in L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right)\cap L^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right)\subset L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right)$
for all $p\in\left[1,\infty\right]$. Furthermore, $1_{0<t<y/T} \in L^2$, so that the same is true of its Fourier transform.

Now Plancherel (Parseval if you want) implies
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(-2\pi is\right)\cdot\mathcal{L}_{W}\left(-2\pi is\right)\cdot\frac{e^{-2\pi iys/T}-1}{-2\pi is}\,{\rm d}s\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{\widehat{g_{I}}\left(s\right)\cdot\widehat{g_{W}}\left(s\right)}\cdot\left(\mathcal{F}1_{0<t<y/T}\right)\left(s\right)\,{\rm d}s\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{\widehat{g}\left(s\right)}\cdot\widehat{1_{0<t<y/T}}\left(s\right)\,{\rm d}s\\
 & \overset{\text{Plancherel}}{=} & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{g\left(t\right)}\cdot1_{0<t<y/T}\,{\rm d}t\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g\left(t\right)\cdot1_{0<t<y/T}\,{\rm d}t.
\end{eqnarray*}
In the first integral, we can now make the substitution $\omega=s/T$
(with ${\rm d}s=T\cdot{\rm d}\omega$), which yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g\left(t\right)\cdot1_{0<t<y/T}\,{\rm d}t\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(-2\pi is\right)\cdot\mathcal{L}_{W}\left(-2\pi is\right)\cdot\frac{e^{-2\pi iys/T}-1}{-2\pi is}\,{\rm d}s\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\mathcal{L}_{W}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\cdot\frac{e^{-2\pi i\omega y}-1}{-2\pi i\omega T}\, T\cdot{\rm d}\omega\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\mathcal{L}_{W}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\cdot\frac{e^{-2\pi i\omega y}-1}{-2\pi i\omega}\,{\rm d}\omega.
\end{eqnarray*}
If we finally integrate this against $f\left(y\right)$ and use Fubini's
theorem, we arrive at
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(y\right)\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g\left(t\right)\cdot1_{0<t<y/T}\,{\rm d}t\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(y\right)\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\mathcal{L}_{W}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\cdot\frac{e^{-2\pi i\omega y}-1}{-2\pi i\omega}\,{\rm d}\omega\,{\rm d}y\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\mathcal{L}_{W}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(y\right)\cdot\frac{e^{-2\pi i\omega y}-1}{-2\pi i\omega}\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}\omega\\
 & \overset{\left(\ast\right)}{=} & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\mathcal{L}_{W}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\left[\frac{1}{-2\pi i\omega}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(y\right)\cdot e^{-2\pi i\omega y}\,{\rm d}y}_{=\mathcal{L}_{F}\left(2\pi i\omega\right)}+\frac{1}{2\pi i\omega}\right]\,{\rm d}\omega\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\mathcal{L}_{W}\left(-2\pi i\omega T\right)\left[\frac{\mathcal{L}_{F}\left(2\pi i\omega\right)-1}{-2\pi i\omega}\right]\,{\rm d}\omega\\
 & \overset{\gamma=-\omega}{=} & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_{I}\left(2\pi i\gamma T\right)\mathcal{L}_{W}\left(2\pi i\gamma T\right)\left[\frac{\mathcal{L}_{F}\left(-2\pi i\gamma\right)-1}{2\pi i\gamma}\right]\,{\rm d}\gamma.
\end{eqnarray*}
At $\left(\ast\right)$, we used the fact that $f$ is a density on
$\left(0,\infty\right)$, so that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f\left(y\right)}{2\pi i\omega}\,{\rm d}y=\frac{1}{2\pi i\omega}.
$$
Hence, the final result is true. I can not completely reproduce the
exact intermediate steps that you posted (I don't completely get the step at the first "?"). But the arguments used in my derivation are essentially the same that are used to justify the last two "?" and the first "?" is similar to what I did above with Plancherel's theorem. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation it actually helps alot :). Going back to my question and specifically the first (?) I have there, it looks to me as if they took the conjugate of both functions in this integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t) 1_{0<t<y/T}$, because they have $\frac{e^{+ 2j\pi y/Ts}-1}{2j\pi s}$ instead of $\frac{ e^{- 2j\pi y/Ts}-1}{- 2j\pi s}$ do you think the paper has a typo?

Comment: Yes, I think it is a typo. But I will think about that more closely this evening or tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @PhoemueX I was wondering if I can ask you one more question regarding your analysis above. The question is, are $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^+$ in your notation or is it complex?

Comment: Above, I always have $\xi \in \Bbb{R}$. Otherwise, you will (for example) only have $\overline{e^{2\pi i x \xi}}= e^{-2\pi i x \overline{\xi}}$ instead of $e^{-2\pi i x \xi}$.

Comment: Thanks for responding, so in general the integrand of this integral  $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathcal{L}_{I}(2 i \pi s T)\mathcal{L}_{W}(2i\pi sT)\times \frac{\mathcal{L_F}(-2i\pi s )-1}{2i\pi s} ds $ is complex, (given that $s \in \mathbb{R}$), do you happen to know why the result of the integral is real in the end ( since its a probability afterall)?

Comment: The "reason" is the last **big** calculation in my proof, which shows that this integral is equal to $\int_0^\infty f(y) \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t) 1_{0<t<y/T} \, dt \, dy$, which is real. But this is not (at all) an intuitive reason. One additional "reason" could be that $\int \widehat{f} (\xi) \cdot \widehat{g}(\xi) \cdot e^{2\pi i x \xi} \, d\xi = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\widehat{f} \cdot \widehat{g}) = f \ast g$ using the **convolution theorem** and Fourier inversion. Here, I have written $\widehat{f}$ for the Fourier transform of $f$, which is closelsy related to the Laplace transform.

Comment: I understand the reasoning thank you very much

Comment: One last question, assume $I,W=0$ then we have $\mathbb{P}(F\geq 0)$, do you think one case say that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathcal{L}(- 2\pi i s )-1}{2\pi i s}ds$ is exactly:  1- the CDF of $ F $ ? where CDF stands for the cumulative density function. @PhoemueX

Comment: Sorry I think I have bothered you :). In any case your answers helped me alot. @Phoemuex